# Extract a number from a string in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a column with data that looks like:

```
7-Day: 320  (5.6%)
```

I need to extract the 320 as a number.  It is not always a 3 digit though.  The value can range from 0 - 9999.  And if it is 0, the percent is not calculated.

A larger block from the column:

```
7-Day: 0
7-Day: 320  (5.6%)
7-Day: 325  (5.5%)
7-Day: 472  (8.5%)
7-Day: 89  (2.5%)
7-Day: 258  (4.4%)
7-Day: 499  (8.7%)
7-Day: 143  (2.4%)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data always starts with the seven characters:

```
7-Day:
```

Then in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)="0",0,MID(A1,8,FIND(CHAR(160),A1)-8))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,3)+0
```

The formula takes the three characters following the first space, then adds a zero, which will coerce text into numbers and ignore spaces.

Copying the data sample from above into Excel, the spaces are non-breaking spaces (character 160), but I assume that in your spreadsheet you will have normal spaces. If your original data has non-breaking spaces, you can use

```
=SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND(" ",A3)+1,3),CHAR(160),"")+0
```